# how to filter mysql data with first letters

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a query which i want to filter by first letters. like

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `uri` FROM `categ` WHERE `active` = 1 AND `parent`='$iParentId'
```

i want this to filter the name with a letter. like filtering it with "a" will return the names starting only with "a". Can anybody show me a example on what to add in this query to get the results only with a particular letter.

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks

The problem is solved. Thanks to SergioTulentsev.

Comment: `WHERE ... AND name LIKE 'a%'`

Comment: "sorting it with "a" will return the names starting only with "a"" - this is not sorting, this is filtering.

Comment: oh! thank you very much and sorry its filtering. my mistake

Comment: i will second @SergioTulentsev.  Please clear your question what you want sorting or filtering??

Comment: Please update your question and title so that people seeing this gets relevant question with relevant answer.

Comment: i edited the question and changed it to filtering.

Answer (score 1):

By sorting , do you mean something like:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `uri` FROM `categ` WHERE `active` = 1 AND `parent`='$iParentId'
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(name, 0, 1) ASC
```

OR if you want to filter, then use:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `uri` FROM `categ` WHERE `active` = 1 AND `parent`='$iParentId'
AND name LIKE 'a%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `uri` FROM `categ` WHERE `active` = 1 AND `parent`='$iParentId' AND `name` LIKE 'a%';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sort particular rows starting with a% then use below query. It will surely help you.

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `uri` FROM `categ` WHERE `active` = 1 AND `parent`='$iParentId' ORDER BY CASE WHEN `name` LIKE 'a%' THEN 0 ELSE ~id END ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the great comment of Sergio, what you seem to be after is called filtering. Not sortering:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `uri` 
FROM `categ` 
WHERE `active` = 1 AND `parent`='$iParentId' AND `name` LIKE 'a%'
```